# How to compare case sensitive strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 strings and check if they are exactly the same. What currently happens is that when I compare 2 strings that have the same characters but different cases, it still returns true.

Comment: Lies. `'foo' == 'Foo' // false` Provide code that shows this occuring

Comment: Maybe you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of one of the equalities operators `==` or `===` to compare strings?

Comment: when i use the === it ignores the case. but == does not.

Comment: @skandal === does not ignore case. == check for equal value === check for equal value and type so, 5 == "5" // true but 5 === "5" // false

Comment: Add some of your tried code

Answer (score -2):

If you want to compare 2 string just use == and for strict comparison use ===. So == check for equal value === check for equal value and type so, 5 == "5" evaluates to true but 5 === "5" evaluates to  false.

```js
 function compare(){
      var s1 = document.getElementById("s1").value.trim();
      var s2 = document.getElementById("s2").value.trim();
      
      if( s1 == s2){
        document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "True"
      }else{
        document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "False"
      }
    }
```

```html
    <html>
      <body>
        <input type="text" id="s1">
        <input type="text" id="s2">
        <div id="compare">
        
        </div>
        <button onclick="compare()">compare</button>
      </body>

    <html>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question on the topic of _case-sensitivity_ of the comparison operators `==` and `===`.